# Swift ScrollView Layout Issue With PageController and Images iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, scrollview, uipagecontrol

I can't figure out how to set constraints for a scrollView with an imageView inside.
I am using the scrollView with a pageConroller to swipe thru a bunch of images.

See my layout in the picture below.

// Code for imageView

```
for index in 0..<drinksImagesArray.count {
        frame.origin.x = scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(index)
        frame.size = scrollView.frame.size
        
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: imagesArray[index].name)
        self.scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
    }
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(imagesArray.count), height: scrollView.frame.size.height)
    scrollView.delegate = self
```

Any suggestions? Thank you!

[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHqYe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have much better luck using auto-layout --- it can handle all of the frame sizes and `.contentSize` for you.

Here's a quick example - it uses a view controller with a scroll view added in Storyboard, so it should be pretty easy for you to integrate with your code:

```
class ScrollingImagesViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    
    var drinksImagesArray: [String] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // however you're populating your array...
        drinksImagesArray = [
            "drink1",
            "drink2",
            "drink3",
            // etc...
        ]

        // create a horizontal stack view
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.axis = .horizontal
        stack.alignment = .fill
        stack.distribution = .fillEqually
        stack.spacing = 0

        // add the stack view to the scroll view
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.addSubview(stack)
        
        // use scroll view's contentLayoutGuide for content constraints
        let svCLG = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // stack view constrained Top / Bottom / Leading / Trailing of scroll view CONTENT guide
            stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: svCLG.topAnchor),
            stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: svCLG.bottomAnchor),
            stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: svCLG.leadingAnchor),
            stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: svCLG.trailingAnchor),
            
            // stack view height == scroll view FRAME height
            stack.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.heightAnchor),
            
        ])

        // create image views and add them to the stack view
        drinksImagesArray.forEach { imgName in
            let v = UIImageView()
            v.backgroundColor = .lightGray
            v.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            // make sure we load a valid image
            if let img = UIImage(named: imgName) {
                v.image = img
            }
            stack.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }
        
        // stack distribution is set to .fillEqually, so we only need to set the
        // width constraint on the first image view
        
        // unwrap it
        if let firstImageView = stack.arrangedSubviews.first {
            firstImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        }
        
    }

}
```

---

**Edit**

After reviewing your Storyboard...

Auto-layout doesn't seem to like it when you add a `UINavigationBar` and a `UIToolbar` and a `UIScrollView` as subviews. In particular, it appears to confuse the scroll view's frame related constraints.

The fix is to first add constraints for your scroll view:

- Top to Navigation Bar Bottom
- Bottom to Page Control Top
- Leading and Trailing to safe-area

Storyboard / Interface builder will complain that the scroll view is not configured properly. You can either ignore that, or select the scroll view and set Ambiguity to Never Verify:

[image]

Then, in your view controller class, we need to create a height constraint for the stack view we're adding to the scroll view, and set that height constant in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`.

Here's the full code:

```
//
//  WasserhaushaltViewController.swift
//  deSynthTheOceans
//
//  Created by robinsonhus0 on 24.03.20.
//  Copyright © 2020 robinsonhus0. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import Charts
import FSCalendar
import HealthKit


struct WasserSpeicher: Codable {
    let wassermenge: Double
    let speicherdatum: String
    let speicherStelle: Double
}

class WasserhaushaltViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var diagrammView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
    
    let drinksImagesArray = ["tapWater", "water", "milk", "cola", "coffee", "tea", "juice", "beer"]

    var imageIndex = Int()
    
    struct Drinks {
        var name: String
        var tagesMengeFactor: Double
        var gesamtMengeFactor: Double
    }
    
    var frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    var pageNumber = CGFloat()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var todaysWaterConsumptionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var waterGoalProgress: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet weak var waterGoalLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var wasserMengeStepper: UIStepper!
    @IBOutlet weak var motivationTextView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var wasserglasButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var kleineFlascheButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var grosseFlascheButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var overAllWaterConsumptionLabel: UILabel!
    
    // added
    let scrollingImagesStackView = UIStackView()
    var stackHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        pageControl.numberOfPages = drinksImagesArray.count
        setupDrinkImages()
    }
    
    
    func setupDrinkImages() {
        // set stack view properties
        scrollingImagesStackView.axis = .horizontal
        scrollingImagesStackView.alignment = .fill
        scrollingImagesStackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        scrollingImagesStackView.spacing = 0
        
        // add the stack view to the scroll view
        scrollingImagesStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.addSubview(scrollingImagesStackView)
        
        // use scroll view's contentLayoutGuide for content constraints
        let svCLG = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // stack view constrained Top / Bottom / Leading / Trailing of scroll view CONTENT guide
            scrollingImagesStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: svCLG.topAnchor),
            scrollingImagesStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: svCLG.bottomAnchor),
            scrollingImagesStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: svCLG.leadingAnchor),
            scrollingImagesStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: svCLG.trailingAnchor),
            
        ])
        
        // create the stack view height constraint - it will be updated in viewDidLayoutSubviews
        stackHeightConstraint = scrollingImagesStackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
        stackHeightConstraint.isActive = true
        
        // create image views and add them to the stack view
        drinksImagesArray.forEach { imgName in
            let v = UIImageView()
            v.backgroundColor = .orange
            v.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            // make sure we load a valid image
            if let img = UIImage(named: imgName) {
                v.image = img
            }
            scrollingImagesStackView.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }
        
        // stack distribution is set to .fillEqually, so we only need to set the
        // width constraint on the first image view
        
        // unwrap it
        if let firstImageView = scrollingImagesStackView.arrangedSubviews.first {
            firstImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        }

        scrollView.delegate = self
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        // since we have a UINavigationBar and a UIToolBar in the view hierarchy,
        //  we need to set this here
        //  Note: if the view size changes
        // stack view height == scroll view FRAME height
        stackHeightConstraint.constant = scrollView.frame.height
        
    }
    
//  func setupDrinkImages() {
//      for index in 0..<drinksImagesArray.count {
//          frame.origin.x = scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(index)
//          frame.size = scrollView.frame.size
//
//          let imageView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
//          imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
//          imageView.image = UIImage(named: drinksImagesArray[index])
//          self.scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
//      }
//      scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(drinksImagesArray.count), height: scrollView.frame.size.height)
//      scrollView.delegate = self
//  }
    
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        pageNumber = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width
        pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
    }
}
```

Your (modified) Storyboard is too big to add here... if you have any trouble with the changes mentioned above, here it is: https://pastebin.com/2Q1uFUgL

Comment: thank you very much.! Thats pretty great, but now the images are overlapping the Navigationcontroller and pagecontrol.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense... in order for the images to overlap something *outside the bounds of the scrollview* you would have to have set `scrollView.clipsToBounds = false` and se the height of the stack view greater than the height of the scroll view frame. If you post the **source** for your Storyboard and the code you are using at pastebin.com I'll take a look.

Comment: @JcbPrn - even if we tried to use teamView, I'd ask for the same thing... just post your Storyboard source and your class code on pastebin.com (or put your whole project on GitHub).

Comment: here the storyboard : https://pastebin.com/5uwBcxPB 
and here is my Swift code : https://pastebin.com/0Atmzn8B
thank you for answering so quickly

Comment: @JcbPrn - see the **Edit** at the bottom of my answer.